# While true try except loop giving different output each time in webscraping - repeats or omits elements while iterating

Tags: python, web-scraping, while-loop, try-except

I am trying to scrape some pages and count occurrences of a word in the page. I have to go through different set of links to reach the final set of pages and I used for loops to collect and iterate through the links.

As the website is slow, I put the final iteration inside a `while True` loop. But each time I run the code, it loops through the final set of links in different ways. For example, it goes through 20 links and then repeats those 20 links again while ignoring another 20 links. Every time the number varies, sometimes within each iteration, repeating and omitting random number of links.

The website is really slow. So unless I put a `while True` loop, the program stops in the middle. Could someone please look through the code and point out what I am doing wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
import time

import csv
d=open('Wyd 20-21.csv','w')
writer=csv.writer(d,lineterminator='\n')

URL = "http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/writereaddata/citizen_out/MAT_DTL_1603_MATD_eng2021.html"
soup = bs(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")
base_url = "http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/"
linksblocks = []
for tag in soup.select("td:nth-of-type(2) a"):
        linksblocks.append(tag["href"])
print(linksblocks)
Allblocks = [base_url+e[6:] for e in linksblocks]
print(Allblocks)#This is the first set of links. I have to iterate through each one of them to get to the second set of links
links = []
for each in Allblocks:
    soup=bs(requests.get(each).content,"html.parser")
    for tag in soup.select("td:nth-of-type(2) a"):
            links.append(tag["href"])
AllGPs = [base_url+e[6:] for e in links]
print(AllGPs)#This is the second set of links. I have to iterate through each one of them to get to the final set of links
gp=0
for each in AllGPs:
        res=requests.get(each)
        soup=bs(res.text,'html.parser')
        urls=[]
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
                urls.append(link.get('href'))
        inte=urls[1:-1]
        each_bill=[base_url+e[6:] for e in inte] #This is the final set of links. I have to iterate through each one of them to get to the final pages and look for the occurrence of the word in each of the page.
        q=len(each_bill)
        print("no of bills is: ",q)
        gp+=1
        x=0
        while True:
            try:
                for each in each_bill:
                        r=requests.get(each)
                        y=r.text.count('Display Board')
                        print(y)
                        soup=bs(r.text,'html.parser')
                        table_soup=soup.findAll('table')
                        trow=[]
                        for tr in table_soup[3]:
                                trow.append(tr)
                        text=trow[1].text
                        b=text[13:]
                        print(b)
                        writer.writerow((y,b))
                        x+=1
                        print("Now Wyd ",x,"th bill in",gp," th GP")
                        if x==q:
                                break
                if x==q:
                    break
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print("exception error: ",e)
                time.sleep(5)
                continue
d.close()
```

Comment: Hi Martineau thanks for editing the question. Could you please share an answer to it based on your expertise?

Comment: Indeed the website is slow. You should use descriptive names for your variables. `x` is the iteration counter, `q` is the number of bills, ... It helps very much when programming, debugging, reviewing, ...